# XCODE 8.2 wrongly detects locked device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode8.2

I get the "Xcode cannot launch MyApp on My iPad because the device is locked. Unlock device to continue" message upon hitting build&run on XCODE 8.2 on an Ipad Air 2 (actual device, not simulator), after "build succeeded" when the device is actually not locked. I tried doing it with locked device in order for it to detect the unlock as usual, to no avail. Clean project, nada. It is quite annoying and happens very often. Has it happened to anyone else, and does anyone know any work around? Seems to be an XCODE 8.2 bug?

Comment: Try turning off the auto-lock temporarily or making the time until auto-lock longer...

Comment: its normal bugs, just unplug and plug again when your phone is unlocked then it will be ok

Comment: I tried plug - unplug and didn't work, the only thing that worked so far is restarting XCODE. With regards to auto-lock, the device does not have it set when this happens, ie device is unlocked and running. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Could you please check your ipad iOS version?

Comment: Hi Dheeraj - it is actually the latest iOS version on iPad and version on project. The issue happens randomly, most times it will run fine but others it will keep falsely detecting a locked device when it's unlocked without changing any settings on device or xcode

Answer (score 5):

I see it very often

*Easiest solution:*

```
Lock your device (e.g. click on side power button) and unlock again.
```

Or you can restart Xcode, but this will take much more time.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try rebooting your phone. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

solution offered by @Karbaman didn't work for me recently.

I cleared it by starting another project in xcode on another device (xcode 9 makes it nice with the wireless networking) and then coming back to the target project.

Still not 'easy', but certainly better than restarting xcode!

UPDATE: Another way that worked for me was the 'simple' method of turning off WiFi on the Mac, waiting for it to not show the connection under 'Devices and Simulators' and then turning WiFi back on.  When it came back up, all my test phones came back as connected.  This certainly seems to be the best method if you have several phones connected!

Answer (score 2):

Quit XCode
Open XCode
Build/run

This should Work for you and as this worked for me.

This is consistently happening from XCode 6, You need to really "Think Different" to solve this kind of issues.

Comment: This is the only working solution for me to fix issue with XCode 9.4.1 over wireless.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue while rebuilding my carthage frameworks.  My iPad was connected, but my iPhone was locked and not connected which is what was being used to build.

> Make sure other devices are not being used wirelessly to build.